# Using multiple conditionals including strings and integers

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm having hard time figuring out what kind of conditionals **and/or** statements should I use in order to achieve the following:

I need to multiply goals scored depending the difference in rank_home & rank_away:

- If rank is lower than opponent: goals_scored * 0.15
- If rank is equal as opponent: goals_scored * 0.30
- If rank is higher than opponent: goals_scored * 0.45

Example: If I want to calculate the points for Ducks (index position 0), I would do:
home_goals * 0.15 because rank_away (Frogs) is lower than rank_home (Ducks)

```
    home_team away_team   rank_home  rank_away  home_goals  away_goals
0   Ducks     Frogs       1          2          4           1
1   Frogs     Eagles      3          3          6           3
2   Eagles    Ducks       2          1          5           5
```

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output for clarity?

Comment: Which would be an example of conditional that uses strings, as per your title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) to get the sign of the difference in rank, use it to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) from a dictionary of factors:

```
factors = {-1: 0.15, 0: 0.30, 1: 0.45}
sign = np.sign(df['rank_home'].sub(df['rank_away']))

df['home_points'] = df['home_goals'].mul(sign.map(factors))
```

output:

```
  home_team away_team  rank_home  rank_away  home_goals  away_goals  home_points
0     Ducks     Frogs          1          2           4           1         0.60
1     Frogs    Eagles          3          3           6           3         1.80
2    Eagles     Ducks          2          1           5           5         2.25
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it using [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html?highlight=select#numpy.select)

```
#define the conditions
cond1 = df['rank_home'] < df['rank_away']
cond2 = df['rank_home'] == df['rank_away']
cond3 = df['rank_home'] > df['rank_away']

# using np.select, assign the weight to each of the condition, 1 being default
# and multiple by home goals to get points
df['points']=np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3],
         [0.15, 0.30, 0.45],
         1) * df['home_goals']
df
```

```
    home_team   away_team   rank_home   rank_away   home_goals  away_goals  points
0   Ducks       Frogs               1            2           4           1  0.60
1   Frogs       Eagles              3            3           6           3  1.80
2   Eagles      Ducks               2            1           5           5  2.25
```

Comment: This worked really well too, thank you for taking the time to help me out!